# Specifying colors for r scatterplot depending on values

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot

I am making a plot to show the relationship between house size and prices. The thing is, I need the 5% of the most recently built houses to have a different color and symbol on the plot.
Here is my code (new_baltimore is the dataframe):

```
    y <- new_baltimore$AGE
    quantile(y, 0.05)   #the result is 4
    k <- subset(new_baltimore, y<=4)
    kk <- k$SQFT
    col = ifelse(any new_baltimore$SQFT %in% kk, "red", "green")
    pch = ifelse(any new_baltimore$SQFT %in% kk, 25, 20)
    plot(new_baltimore$SQFT, PRICE, col=col, pch=pch)
```

R gives me the errors

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "col = ifelse(any new_baltimore"
Error: unexpected symbol in "pch = ifelse(any new_baltimore"
```

Any help?

edit: This is the reproducible data:

```
baltimore_struct <-
  structure(
    list(
      new_baltimore.SQFT = c(
        11.25,
        28.92,
        30.62,
        26.12,
        22.04,
        39.42,
        21.88,
        25.6,
        44.12,
        19.88,
        12.08,
        10.99,
        12.8,
        29.79,
        14.3,
        13.72,
        11.84,
        18.06,
        10.72,
        8.96,
        14.38,
        36.75,
        20,
        22.82,
        24.86,
        19.2,
        11.58,
        26,
        14.4,
        11.62,
        23.08,
        23.76,
        15.6,
        10,
        22.8,
        16.76,
        22.1,
        14.28,
        15.36,
        16,
        23.04,
        24.94,
        11.82,
        12.88,
        11.2,
        18.12,
        38.25,
        17.68,
        19.02,
        32.8,
        15.16,
        21.975,
        12.6,
        23.52,
        17.52,
        47.61,
        20.55,
        35.52,
        8.4,
        13.68,
        14.48,
        12.8,
        12.8,
        18,
        15.4,
        10.08,
        8.96,
        8.96,
        20,
        12.88,
        12,
        18.16,
        14.28,
        26,
        12.02,
        20.8,
        11.78,
        8.68,
        17.6,
        11.4,
        44.55,
        46.32,
        10.24,
        9.6,
        31.2,
        26.4,
        13.6,
        27.48,
        17.86,
        18.04,
        14.84,
        10.46,
        14.56,
        6.96,
        9.5,
        11.86,
        12.88,
        12.32,
        6.72,
        10.08,
        15.6,
        6.72,
        11.52,
        11.76,
        10.24,
        11.52,
        9.28,
        6.72,
        15.6,
        15.5,
        9.84,
        15.6,
        13.76,
        10.24,
        5.76,
        10.08,
        11.52,
        12.15,
        9.77,
        15,
        14.4,
        14.5,
        22.54,
        10.24,
        7.8,
        8.4,
        10.92,
        42.9,
        9,
        10.5,
        10.08,
        12.6,
        8.96,
        8.58,
        7.56,
        10.8,
        13.44,
        10.24,
        14.44,
        12.24,
        13.2,
        9.6,
        15.22,
        24.16,
        10.24,
        10.24,
        9.88,
        23.2,
        17.68,
        24.3,
        35.94,
        21.6,
        11.02,
        21,
        23.92,
        14.4,
        28,
        11.44,
        21.94,
        10.24,
        16.86,
        9.92,
        13.44,
        12,
        14.76,
        8.96,
        11.52,
        8.64,
        8.12,
        11.12,
        11.28,
        10.36,
        11.52,
        17.1,
        17.52,
        10.73,
        11.2,
        12.8,
        12,
        41.07,
        12.8,
        22.36,
        10.56,
        13.44,
        11.02,
        17.98,
        18.88,
        11.76,
        9.36,
        11.52,
        27.3,
        23.04,
        17.68,
        13.36,
        11.6,
        11.52,
        9.98,
        12.96,
        11.13,
        19.6,
        11.52,
        12.16,
        0,
        10.64
      ),
      PRICE2 = c(
        47,
        113,
        165,
        104.3,
        62.5,
        70,
        127.5,
        64.5,
        145,
        63.5,
        58.9,
        65,
        48,
        3.5,
        12.8,
        17.5,
        36,
        41.9,
        53.5,
        24.5,
        24.5,
        55.5,
        60,
        51,
        46,
        46,
        44,
        54.9,
        42.5,
        44,
        44.9,
        37.9,
        33,
        43.9,
        49.6,
        52,
        37.5,
        50,
        35.9,
        42.9,
        107,
        112,
        44.9,
        55,
        102,
        35.5,
        62.9,
        39,
        110,
        8,
        62,
        85.9,
        57,
        110,
        67.7,
        89.5,
        70,
        74,
        13,
        48,
        24,
        53.5,
        34.5,
        53,
        87.5,
        33.5,
        24,
        9.6,
        30,
        41,
        30,
        38.9,
        20.7,
        49.9,
        18.6,
        39,
        34,
        16,
        18.9,
        15.2,
        41.5,
        53,
        22,
        24.9,
        6.7,
        32.5,
        30,
        59,
        29.5,
        26,
        16.5,
        39,
        48.9,
        33.5,
        46,
        54,
        57.9,
        37.9,
        32,
        31,
        34,
        29,
        32.5,
        51.9,
        31,
        41.8,
        48,
        28,
        35,
        46.5,
        51.9,
        35.4,
        16,
        35,
        35,
        36.5,
        35.9,
        45,
        40,
        35,
        38,
        37,
        23,
        25.5,
        39.5,
        21.5,
        9,
        67.5,
        13.4,
        12.5,
        28.5,
        23,
        33.5,
        9,
        11,
        30.9,
        31.65,
        33,
        33.4,
        47,
        40,
        46,
        45.5,
        57,
        29.9,
        30,
        34,
        51,
        64.5,
        57.5,
        85.5,
        61,
        38,
        56.5,
        60.4,
        51.5,
        54,
        69,
        56,
        27.9,
        37.5,
        32.9,
        22,
        29.9,
        39.9,
        32.6,
        38.5,
        21.5,
        25.9,
        27.5,
        22.9,
        31.5,
        8.5,
        5.5,
        33,
        57,
        47,
        43.5,
        43.9,
        68.5,
        44.25,
        61,
        40,
        44.5,
        57,
        35,
        35.1,
        64.5,
        40,
        42.6,
        50,
        58,
        58,
        55,
        43,
        54,
        39,
        45,
        42,
        38.9,
        43.215,
        26.5,
        30,
        29.5
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(
      1L,
      2L,
      3L,
      4L,
      5L,
      6L,
      7L,
      8L,
      9L,
      10L,
      11L,
      12L,
      13L,
      14L,
      15L,
      16L,
      17L,
      18L,
      19L,
      20L,
      21L,
      22L,
      23L,
      24L,
      25L,
      26L,
      27L,
      28L,
      29L,
      30L,
      31L,
      32L,
      33L,
      34L,
      35L,
      36L,
      37L,
      38L,
      39L,
      40L,
      41L,
      42L,
      43L,
      44L,
      45L,
      46L,
      47L,
      48L,
      49L,
      50L,
      51L,
      53L,
      54L,
      55L,
      56L,
      57L,
      58L,
      59L,
      60L,
      61L,
      62L,
      63L,
      64L,
      65L,
      66L,
      67L,
      68L,
      69L,
      70L,
      71L,
      72L,
      73L,
      74L,
      75L,
      76L,
      77L,
      78L,
      79L,
      80L,
      81L,
      82L,
      83L,
      84L,
      85L,
      86L,
      87L,
      88L,
      89L,
      90L,
      91L,
      92L,
      93L,
      94L,
      95L,
      96L,
      97L,
      98L,
      99L,
      100L,
      101L,
      102L,
      103L,
      104L,
      105L,
      106L,
      107L,
      108L,
      109L,
      110L,
      111L,
      112L,
      113L,
      114L,
      115L,
      116L,
      117L,
      118L,
      119L,
      120L,
      121L,
      122L,
      123L,
      124L,
      125L,
      126L,
      127L,
      128L,
      129L,
      130L,
      131L,
      132L,
      133L,
      134L,
      135L,
      136L,
      137L,
      138L,
      139L,
      140L,
      141L,
      142L,
      143L,
      144L,
      145L,
      146L,
      147L,
      148L,
      149L,
      150L,
      151L,
      152L,
      153L,
      154L,
      155L,
      156L,
      157L,
      158L,
      159L,
      160L,
      161L,
      162L,
      163L,
      164L,
      165L,
      166L,
      167L,
      168L,
      169L,
      170L,
      171L,
      172L,
      173L,
      174L,
      175L,
      176L,
      177L,
      178L,
      179L,
      180L,
      181L,
      182L,
      183L,
      184L,
      185L,
      186L,
      187L,
      188L,
      189L,
      190L,
      191L,
      192L,
      193L,
      194L,
      195L,
      196L,
      197L,
      198L,
      199L,
      200L,
      201L,
      202L,
      203L,
      204L,
      205L
    ),
    class = "data.frame"
  )
```

edit2: I found the error, I just had to remove the any in the ifelse commands. So the correct  code looks like this

```
col = ifelse(new_baltimore$SQFT %in% kk, "red", "green")
pch = ifelse(new_baltimore$SQFT %in% kk, 25, 20)
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: @Quinten I did! Sorry, this was my first time using dput and it took me some time.

Answer (score 0):

next time, please try to provide some `reproducible data`. It makes it easier for others to help you. You can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

I tried to generate some data on my own. Hope it fits your data. I recommend using the [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) as it contains a lot of useful packages for manipulating and visualising data. `library(tidyverse)` loads all packages from the tidyverse but you can also load only the necessary packages such as `dplyr` for data manipulation or `ggplot2` for data visualisation. See comments for further details:

```
#install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse) 

# generate some data
data <- data.frame(
  age = sample(c(10:50), 100, replace=TRUE),
  price = sample(c(50000:1000000), 100, replace=TRUE),
  size = sample(c(200:500), 100, replace=TRUE)
)

# save threshold
threshold <- quantile(data$age, 0.05) 

plot_data <- data %>%
  mutate(groups = factor(ifelse(age<threshold, "newer", "older"))) # mutate generates a new variable in the data and you can define groups based on conditions

ggplot(plot_data, 
       aes(x=size, y=price, group=groups, color=groups, shape=groups)) + # here you specify the mappings of the aesthetics and group the data depending on the groups variable that corresponds to our threshold
  geom_point(size=4) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("aquamarine4","burlywood")) + # control color aesthetic
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(18, 19)) + # control shape aesthetic
  theme_classic() # this one of a lot of predefined themes
```

[image: Example]

Hope that helps.

Comment: I shared the data, sorry it took me a bit of time, never used dput before. Thank you for the answer, I will give it a try now.